# For Newton's method, how to prove that $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}\dfrac{|x_{k+1}-x^*|}{|x_k-x^*|}=0$?

Tags: analysis, optimization, numerical-methods

I want to prove the following theorem for the convergence of Newton's method:

Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$, $f'(x^*)=0$, $f''(x^*)\neq0$, $x_{k+1}=x_{k}-\dfrac{f'(x_k)}{f''(x_k)}$. If $x_0$ is close enough to $x^*$, then we have

(1) $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}x_k=x^*$

(2) $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}\dfrac{|x_{k+1}-x^*|}{|x_k-x^*|}=0$

(3) If $f\in C^3$, then $|x_{k+1}-x^*|=O(|x_k-x^*|^2)$

But I can only prove the first part:

$$\left|x_{k+1}-x^*\right|=\left|\dfrac{1}{f''(x_k)}\int_{x^*}^{x_k}(f''(x_k)-f''(x))\mathrm d x\right|\leq \dfrac{1}{2}|x_{k}-x^*|,$$
noticing that for small $\epsilon$, $\exists \delta>0$ such that $x,y\in(x^*-\delta,x^*+\delta)\implies |f''(x)-f''(y)|\leq\epsilon \leq \dfrac{1}{4}|f''(x^*)|\leq\dfrac{1}{2}|f''(x)|$.

I don't see how to improve the estimation to improve the results. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm just computing a solution to $f'(x)=0$ instead of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f\in C^3$

$$
0 = f'(x^*) = f'(x_n) + f''(x_n) (x^* - x_n) + o(x^*-x_n)^2
$$

dividing by $f''(x_n)$,

$$
0 = \frac{f'(x_n)}{f''(x_n)}+x^*-x_n + o(x^*-x_n)^2 \Leftrightarrow x^* - x_{n+1} = o(x^*-x_n)^2
$$

However, even if $f\in C^2$ the remainder in Taylor's formula is still going to zero, and the result holds.